# Attaching integer textures to a framebuffer

Tags: opengl, graphics, textures, framebuffer, render-to-texture

I'm trying to attach a texture with internal format `GL_R32UI` to a framebuffer, to be used as an ID-buffer. However, `glCheckFramebufferStatus` keeps coming up with `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`, even when it is the only attachment.

This is very strange to me because the OpenGL 4.2 specs seems to state the `GL_R32UI` is one of the formats that OpenGL implementations must support when attached to framebuffers. I'm suspecting that this is a driver bug. Am I right, or can anyone show me what I am overlooking?

Comment: What are you using as format?

Comment: I think you're inching towards the solution I just worked out :)

Comment: Glad its working :). I found it in the [spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec43.core.20120806.pdf) at page 163 if you are interested.

Comment: Ah, I see. Now I know where to look.

Answer (score 8):

I solved my own problem.

```
void glTexImage2D(GLenum target,
    GLint level,
    GLint internalFormat,
    GLsizei width,
    GLsizei height,
    GLint border,
    GLenum format,
    GLenum type,
    const GLvoid * data);
```

When calling `glTexImage2D` to create the texture, the 7th parameter 'format' needs to correspond to the 3rd 'internalFormat' parameter, even if you are passing a null pointer for the data parameter. If your internal format is an integral format, you need to supply a format like `GL_RED_INTEGER`, and not a format like `GL_RED`.

Comment: Note that a tool like [glIntercept](http://code.google.com/p/glintercept/) would allow you to detect this error by giving you an error message. So would employing a debug context and the ARB_debug_output extension.